# Release one iOS app with multiple (foreign lang.) names?

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to re-release an existing iOS app with a different title?

The app supports multiple languages, but only has an English title in the app store. My thinking, which could very likely be wayward, is that my potential Russian/Indian/Chinese/French audiences have no visibility of it.

Doesn't sound like something Apple would support, but thought I'd ask anyway.

If in the slim chance it is do-able, what would I need in the way of bundle id's/prov profiles/dist certificates? One of each per app?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

Yes you can - just localise the value of `CFBundleDisplayName`:

1. Open your project in Xcode
2. Make sure the Project Navigator is in view *(View > Navigators > Show Project Navigators, or CMD+1)*
3. Make sure the File Inspector is in view *(View > Utilities > Show File Inspector, or OPT+CMD+1)*
4. Select **InfoPlist.strings** in the Project Navigator
5. In the File Inspector, under Localization click the + button and add the language you want to translate into (e.g. French)
6. In the Project Navigator, expand the disclosure triangle that now appears next to InfoPlist.strings and select InfoPlist.string (French)
7. Add the following line:

   ```
   CFBundleDisplayName = "Translated app name here";
   ```

[image: Xcode screenshot illustrating the above steps]

As @runmad has suggested, you can also provide localised marketing content in iTunes Connect, including a localised app name. This is not obligatory, although it does make sense. Note however that iTunes Connect only supports a small set of languages. The languages currently support for localisation in iTunes Connect at listed in Apple's [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) (PDF). As of the current version of that document (7.4) the languages supported are:

- Australian English
- Brazilian Portuguese
- Canadian English
- Dutch
- English
- French
- French Canadian
- German
- Italian
- Japanese
- Korean
- Latin American Spanish
- Portuguese
- Russian
- Simplified Chinese
- Spanish
- Swedish
- UK English

If you want to localise the app name to a language outside that list (let's say, Hungarian) you can do that just fine using the process outlined above in Xcode, and the name you provide in Xcode is the name that a Hungarian user will see when they install your app on their device, but in the Hungarian App Store the app will be listed under (I assume) its English name.

Comment: Thanks Simon for the detailed response.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is. You'll need to localize the app in iTunes Connect for all the countries, including app name and description.

Finally you will also need to [localize your app's bundle ID](http://kb.applingua.com/2011/10/how-to-localize-app-names/).

Comment: damn' you runmad, you were fast

Comment: Many thanks. This might be dumb but can if it's just the app store name I wish to 'foreignise', can I just re-use the same binary as the English version, if I create a new app in itunes connect? Or do I need to get new provisioning/dist certificates etc and do a new build?

Comment: You release it under the same bundle ID. That's why you just localize the display name for your app once it's installed on your user's device as well as the App Store display name in iTunes Connect.