# AppStore App name per language

Tags: ios, itunes, publish

I have an App published to the Appstore. I added the infos for english and german. (Screenshots and so on). Now I realize, that the App name is in English for english and german.

Where do I change the Appname for german ? Or in other words, where can I setup the appname for different languages ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Do you have a hint where to find information for this ? Or where to ask ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Release one iOS app with multiple (foreign lang.) names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300086/release-one-ios-app-with-multiple-foreign-lang-names)

Comment: check this link may be helps you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html